# Data Logical organization

Tags: database, normalization

I have two tables: counterparties and customers. And both have an address field. I don't know, would it be better if I create third table "addresses"?

The first way:

> **Counterparty**
>
> - id
> - name
> - city
> - streetname
> - room
>
> **Customer**
>
> - id
> - firstName
> - lastName
> - city
> - streetname
> - room

The second way:

> **Counterparty**
>
> - id
> - name
> - addressID
>
> **Customer**
>
> - id
> - firstName
> - lastName
> - addressID
>
> **Address**
>
> - id
> - city
> - streetname
> - room

What is better way?

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is better, unless either:

1. you have customers which are also counterparties (but then you should change the whole schema design), *or*
2. several customers and/or counterparties have the same address (for instance they are in the same building).

There are no other reasons to choose the second solution.